# Error in MySQL access denied Laravel and Cloudways

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cloudways

I just moved my application to production, I am using Cloudways and DigitalOcean, but when I try to log in to my application this error comes out:
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = test@gmail.com limit 1)

My site was on localhost using apache and phpmyadmin, but now I don't know if I should create the table on the MySQL section that Cloudways offers? or if I just need to change some things on my .env

This is what I have on my .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:d2WQTk7Xg07LkV1ca/V02s5jpkA/UM1hEprWYcG2I0w=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=chsv
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=leti.nava2303@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=letynavac230394
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

I would appreciate any help,

Thank you.

Comment: You need to put in the user/pass for your mysql database. Talk to your host to find out what it might be.

Answer (score 1):

On the "Access Detail" page for your Application on the Cloudways Platform, you will find details for how to access the MySQL database for that particular application. As suggested in the comment as well, you need to find out the correct MySQL database access credentials from the Platform and edit your config file to reflect that.

Comment: `https://platform.cloudways.com/apps/HASH/access_detail` is what my url path looked like.